# applying individual effects to images from a slide div

Tags: jquery, cycle

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/div.html

this example works by switching the whole .slideshow.slide div, i want to keep switching this block like the example BUT i want to apply the switch effect (the fx) to images individually, how can i do that?

like when i click on slide 2 the 3 images  from the current slide get some effect and you get the slide 2 results

Answer (score 0):

You want to slide by individual images, not by groups of 3?

Just set the class on each image to slide. If that doesn't work, put each imagine in its own div and have each div have the slide class.

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <img src="whatever" class="slide" />
  <img src="whatever" class="slide" />
  <img src="whatever" class="slide" />
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide"><img src="whatever" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="whatever" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="whatever" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nop, i want to slide groups of photos but apply the transition effect to every single image of that block, individually...